# Find the real and imaginary parts in the given expression:

Tags: complex-numbers

$$(z+1)^2=u(r,\theta)+iv(r,\theta)$$

We are learning how to apply the polar form of the Cauchy-Riemann equations. I understand how to do this using the C-R equations the non-polar way, but I'm at a total loss when doing it in polar form. My guess would be to first convert $(z+1)^2$ into polar form?

Update - I still need help on this. I'm doing it the long way in terms of $x,y$ but I don't understand how to work the problem entirely in polar form.

Comment: Right. What's $z$ in polar form?

Answer (score 1):

Hint assume $z=u+iv$ so on expanding we get $x^2+2xiy-y^2+2x+2iy+1$ thus $(x+1)^2-y^2+i(2xy+2y)$ these imaginary and real parts now use $tan^{-1}(v/u)$ to find argument and $\sqrt{u^2+v^2}$ to find modulus=r and then express in terms of $f(z)=(r,\theta)$

Comment: That's the long way!

Comment: Then thats the safest way any good way you know

Comment: Why not substitute in $z=re^{i\theta}$?

Comment: Anyhow you have to find modulus and also its a must for z to be expressed as $z=x+iy$ that will take same steps

Comment: I don't follow you. The modulus is $r$.

Comment: Yes how will you express z if we have replaced it

Comment: Can you give an answer so that i understand you

Comment: $u(r,\theta)=(1+r\cos \theta)^2-r^2\sin^2 \theta$. You can figure out $v(r,\theta)$.

Comment: Oh thanks !!! I got it

Comment: @OliverJones care to elaborate a bit more?

Comment: @ArchisWelankar I found that $\theta = arctan(\frac{2xy+2y}{(x+1)^2})$ and $r=\sqrt{(x+1)^4+(4x^2y^2+8xy^2+4y^2)}$, but then what?

Comment: That's not the correct approach. Look at my comment above.